# Proper use of the phrase "of all time"

Tags: idioms, american-english, colloquialisms

I have a client who insists on using the following sentence in his web site:

> Lance Armstrong is the most successful American bike racer of all times.

I think that "of all times" should be "of all time".

Which is correct?

Comment: "I'mma let you finish, but Beyonce had one of the best videos of all time!" Seems like Kanye West agrees with you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Of all times" and "of all time" are **different** expressions. They are both in vogue, both are correct, but they **mean different things**.

The phrase most appropriate for your situation would be "of all time." "Of all time" is used to make a comparison, stating that something is the best throughout the ages.

"Of all times" has a different meaning and usage. "Of all times" is used to mean *the wrong time*. For example:

> James rocked up, of all times, while we were in the middle of a fight.

Thus, if your friend were to write "of all times," he would be using a wrong expression--still an expression, but the incorrect one in this case.

Comment: The expression "of all times" means of all *possible* times, the set of all moments something could have happened. So, "now of all times" suggests that now is the worst time of all the possible times. Whereas "all time" means all of eternity as a single unit.

Comment: You can tell the difference by looking for a superlative (_best, most, least_) preceding _of all time_, which always occurs with a superlative. The plural idiom, by contrast, is a self-contained interjection.

Comment: Can you possibly tell whether the "of all time" version implies "among all bike racers" or "only among American bike racers?