# A word for when a word is used incorrectly (grammatically) but can still be parsed in a grammatically correct way?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, rhetoric, puns, catachresis

Does such a word exist?

An example:

*Do good.*

Supposing that my intention in saying "Do good!" was actually "Do well (on your test)!", the sentence still parses correctly as "Do good (deeds)!"

I will attempt to think of more examples and update this if/when I do.

This seems related to a pun in some way, but I was unable to find information about it. (Without knowing the word to begin with, I find it very difficult to navigate wikipedia when looking for "pun-related" words. I.e. It took me forever to find *tom swifty* and *paraprosdokian*.)

Comment: Also, [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42023/8183), in which the phrase "of all times" was used in the wrong way.

Comment: Do note that when someone uses "Do good" to say "Do well", that this is not in anyway incorrect grammatically, but only semantically(!).

Comment: @Unreason: isn't that begging the question? If "Play good" is ungrammatical, "Do good" is equally so; the fact that in another context it would be proper seems irrelevant.  Or do you consider that a word is not misspelled if, by chance, the misspelling takes the form of another genuine word?

Comment: @TimLymington, if the word is misspelled in such a way that it takes form of another word, then indeed you may say that there are no spelling errors in the resulting sentence. *If* you know what was supposed to be written you may call it misspelling. The thing is that you need to know what was meant - and that is the matter of semantics. So, in fact I believe that in label this as primarily a matter of semantics (and only latter matter of grammar, syntax or spelling) I think I assume less of initial points as compared to calling it ungrammatical or misspelled (where you assume meaning).

Comment: If you're after examples, the Adam and Joe radio show (and podcast) has a feature called 'Eggcorns'. The podcast is at http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/adamandjoe, but a quick google shows it seems to have spawned a website or two: http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/contribute/ , for example.

Comment: ...actually, the term may predate the show. Oh well, it's still relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few names for (rhetoric) vices that refer to using wrong words or wrong expressions at wrong places.

You are probably looking for [acyrologia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/A/acyrologia.htm),

> An incorrect use of words, especially the use of words that sound alike but are far in meaning from the speaker's intentions.
>       Note: Malapropisms are a kind of acyrologia.

or [malapropism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism),

> A malapropism is an act of misusing or the habitual misuse of similar sounding words, especially with humorous results.

Related vice is also [catachresis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/C/catachresis.htm),

> The use of a word in a context that differs from its proper application.

You might want to go through [the list of vices](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/groupings/Vices.htm) to better define what you are looking for in according to existing classifications.

Comment: +1 Nice term, "acryologia". I'll try to remember that!

Comment: from Gk. *a*, "not", *kyros*, "authority,"and *logos*, "speech". Also sp. *acirilogia, acyron, improprietas*

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that any of these *fully* encapsulates the idea, but they're all very close.

Answer (score 4):

I think @Unreason's answer is fantastic, especially *catachersis*.

These kinds of errors could be considered *[solecisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solecism)*, but the pun-like element is an interesting twist.

Generally, puns are understood as intentional wordplay.  Here, there's a tension between an inadvertent mistake, and an outcome which has a double-meaning, or can be understood as being as being a pun within a certain frame of reference.

Comment: Good link to solecism, it is certainly related to the issue. However, OP specifically wants figures that *are* grammatical, which disqualifies it.

Comment: @Unreason -- I think you're probably right, though I wasn't certain from the OP's question that grammatical correctness was assumed. I wasn't taking 'parsable' to mean it absolutely adhered to a strict grammar, only that it was understandable from within the framework of that grammar.

Answer (score 4):

The use of ‘good’ as an adverb meaning something like ‘in a satisfctory manner’ is no more than a non-standard dialect form. It is found in the comments of British football supporters who allegedly say ‘The boy done good.’

Comment: I realize, it was purely an example. Where I live it's more common to hear good as adverb than to hear "well" at all.