# Is there a word to describe someone who often inaccurately uses words?

Tags: expressions, adjectives, pejorative-language, epithet-requests, catachresis

Or a word to describe the act of inaccurately using complicated or unusual words (often in an attempt to sound more intelligent)?

I considered 'bombastic' but it doesn't have that quality of inaccuracy.

Comment: The title of your post is different to the question in full. For the latter "pretentious" is a suitable term. Bombastic means something else entirely i.e. crazy cool.

Comment: Related: [A word for when a word is used incorrectly (grammatically) but can still be parsed in a grammatically correct way?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42071/1547)

Comment: @Chris: I don't think that's the primary meaning of *bombastic*.

Comment: Inconcievable!!

Comment: First: You actually mean "... someone who often uses words inaccurately". Right? As it stands now, it means the inaccurate usage of probably the right word.

Comment: "Affectatious sesquipedalianism"?

Comment: I was trying to think of a good adjective to go along with sesquipedalian to indicate they are using the large words inaccurately.

Comment: @Kris, no, it's obvious from context what "inaccurately" modifies, regardless of its position. Adverbs do not have strict positional requirements except in cases where a non-trivial chance of actual ambiguity is present (there is no such chance in this case).

Comment: @BenLee The "such chance" is shown in my comment.

Answer (score 25):

The act of using a word inaccurately could be called *catachresis*. [*Catachresis* is defined as:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/catachresis?__utma=1.1138480261.1347974681.1347974681.1348188307.2&__utmb=1.4.10.1348188307&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1348188307.2.2.utmcsr=dictionary.reference.com|utmccn=%28referral%29|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/browse/malapropism&__utmv=-&__utmk=81336343) "the misuse or strained use of words, as in a mixed metaphor, occurring either in error or for rhetorical effect." [Or as:](https://www.google.com/webhp?source=search_app#hl=en&tbo=u&q=catachresis&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=g7lbUIiNNKf30gG-_IDYDw&ved=0CCsQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=239f21ab760ce758&biw=1433&bih=724) "The use of a word in a way that is not correct, for example, the use of *mitigate* for *militate.*

It has the adjective form of *catachrestic*.

This entry in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catachresis) says catachresis can be either unintentional or intentional. It's a fun word to say. Just be sure YOU use it correctly.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the word, but I sincerely think this is not really the scenario the OP is referring to. *Catachresis* usually deals with mixed metaphors and is broad in the sense that it can be *intentional* or *unintentional*, more like *cacography*. While I think the OP is trying to describe a person who simply doesn't know the right words but **just tries to use big words to feel important**.

Comment: Also don't think this is quite it.  Catachresis can also be intentional and used intelligently.  Your second example (mitigate) is also more of a malaprosism than catachresis (as in @david wallace's answer).

Comment: @UpTheCreek, Yep, it can be intentional (as I said). There are examples of Shakespeare using it intentionally. But it also has the meaning of "Misuse of a word out of a misunderstanding of its meaning.
*The runner literally flew down the track.*" (from the Wikipedia link).

Comment: @JLG - Surely that's not an example of someone misunderstanding the word 'flew' though - but rather being very liberal with its use (to the point of it being technically wrong).

Comment: @UpTheCreek, It is an example of using the word *literally* incorrectly.

Comment: @JLG - I didn't say it wasn't incorrect, just not an mistake based on *misunderstanding* the word.

Comment: @UpTheCreek, I think, in that example, the mistake is based on a misunderstanding of the meaning of the word *literally.*

Comment: @JLG - I misread your last comment, sorry! :)

Answer (score 22):

It's a [malapropism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/malapropism) and you may address the person who uses such as [Mrs Malaprop](http://plays.about.com/b/2010/06/29/who-is-mrs-malaprop.htm).

Comment: The way I read it, a malapropism must be a substitution of an similar sounding word; although *what is similar* may be a bit subjective.

Comment: I agree with Jim. affect/effect would be one example.  I think this is a specific case, whereas the question was more general.

Answer (score 7):

I think your description of this person requires two words:

1 "inaccurately using complicated or unusual words" = *ignorant*.

2 "in an attempt to sound more intelligent" = *pompous, pretentious*

Although *bombastic*, *pompous*, and *pretentious* are often synonymous, each has a different connotation and use. Of these three, I think that only *pretentious* implies the probability or possibility of ignorance and misuse of words. *Pomposity* and *bombast* imply overdramatization rather than deceit.

Comment: I'm not so sure *pretentious* says anything about possible ignorance or misuse of words.

Comment: @Jim: I'm not so sure either. But it **is** related to _pretending_. I thought of _malapropism_ but rejected that because Mrs Malaprop wasn't intentionally deceitful or pompous or, perhaps, not even unaware of the correct word when calm and uninvolved in conversation, only confused, but a pretentious person is deliberately pompous, probably unconcerned about using the wrong word, and so doesn't mind being an intentional or unintentional fraud. Mrs Malaprop wasn't a fraud, just an accidental comedienne. I may be stretching things a bit here. I see that Chris suggested _pretentious_ too.

Comment: I believe that it is entirely possible for one to sound pretentious without making a mistake ;)

Comment: Yes, it is. No argument from me on that one. But pretending that one knows something one doesn't is also pretentious. Then, too, pretension (pretentiousness) is almost always a mistake, n'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 6):

The word you're looking for is acyrologia.  The person who uses such words could probably be called an acyrolog, although that's a bit of a neologism.

If the words being confused are similar sounding, you're dealing with a subcategory of acyrologia called a malapropism or (less frequently) a dogberryism.  Mrs. Malaprop is a character in [*The Rivals* by Richard Brinsley Sheridan](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/24761/pg24761.html).  Dogberry is a character in [Shakespeare's *Much Ado About Nothing*](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2240/pg2240.html).

Catachresis can also be the misuse of words, although it connotes an intentional misuse done for a rhetorical purpose.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the bed. +1

Answer (score 4):

For part (2) of your question

> Or a word to describe the act of inaccurately using complicated or unusual words (often in an attempt to sound more intelligent)?

Henry Fowler refers to them as "genteelisms" in his book *Modern English Usage*.

Comment: "A word or expression used because it is thought to be socially more acceptable than the everyday word."

Answer (score 3):

Given the description, and if you're trying to use it to give something a bit of colour rather than looking for the technical word to describe the way the words are used, I think my favourite descriptive pick would be bluster, or blustering.  While not a definite hit for the specific case of using long or complicated words, it certainly carries a self-important air along with the implication of inaccuracy or exaggeration, and the specifics could easily (and, perhaps, entertainingly) be elaborated on later.

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re actually looking for two different concepts.

Where trying to sound more intelligent is concerned I’d be tempted to use the word *affected*, in the sense of “assumed or displayed artificially; put on for effect; artificial, stilted, ‘got up’ ”  (source Oxford English Dictionary).

There was a great line in an episode of Frasier where, describing such a person, Frasier said, “Nothing is quite so irksome as affected erudition.”

In terms of using words incorrectly, *incorrect* or any of its variants will do.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is [malapropism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malapropism).

The term comes from the 18th Century play *The Rivals*, which satirises the tendency you have described.  In the play there is a character called Mrs. Malaprop who habitually confuses impressive-sounding Latinate words to great comic effect.  Her name reflects the phrase *mal a propos*, which is borrowed from French and means ill-suited.

Comment: This answer was provided already, just FYI: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/83235/22507

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're mainly referring to the scenario where someone simply uses big incorrect words simply to sound intelligent or smart.

I personally don't think there's currently any one word for this but this can often be observed in people who have low self-esteem and often want to exaggerate their importance.

In that case, I think you can call them **grandiose** and they can be said to be *ego-deprived*.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be looking for acyrologia.  It's a form of rhetoric that covers things like malapropism and cacozelia.

Comment: Before posting an answer, please check that nobody else has already suggested the same thing.