# What is a term for using a large word that the speaker/writer clearly thinks means something other than what it does?

Tags: word-choice, pejorative-language

A lot of times I'll hear a politician or see a [commenter in a public forum](http://www.npr.org/blogs/itsallpolitics/2014/03/14/290238727/long-dead-congressmans-earmark-lives-on-in-europe#comment-1296632132) where they clearly think the meaning of one or more words they use is something other than the real meaning. Is there a term for this type of "near miss?"

Comment: Are you sure that the mistake always lies with the politician rather than yourself? The typical politician is skilled in choosing words that can be interpreted in more than one way (former British PM Harold Wilson's  "pragmatic" was a classic), though some politicians do seem to make more gaffes than others. I can't find a mistake in article you link to: could you please point out the one you have identified.

Comment: The late Ernest Bevin, Minister of Labour in Churchill's wartime coalition, and subsequently Foreign secretary in the post-war Labour Government was noted for his Malapropisms and mis-pronunciations. Bevin left school at 13, and worked as a drayman before rising through the Trade Union movement to found the Transport and General Workers Union.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Reasonably so. I was raised by an English teacher. If you looked at the link on mobile you might not have realized that the link was not to the article, but to the comment thread. Once the page fully loads, do a search on "Amy" and you should be able to pinpoint what I was pointing to.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship:  What does the word 'supine' mean to you?

Comment: Some people would definitely call it an anachronism.

Comment: AHD: **supine** 2. Having the palm upward. Used of the hand. >> This is skilfully used by the commenter in the linked article as a synonym for 'having adopted a begging posture', a metonym for 'having a beggarly attitude'. He explains this elliptically. Hardly a good example of catachresis.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Putting aside OP's example and just dealing with the question at face value, *catachresis* wouldn't be a bad answer.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: Those who are not immediately dismissing your question as a duplicate are getting distracted by your ill-chosen example. I think you should consider editing your question with better examples. Perhaps someone uses *obviate* when they mean "to make obvious". I personally know of someone who consistently and intentionally uses *concatenate* to mean "truncate", because she honestly believes that's what it means.

Comment: @John Y [It was](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=catachresis) a good answer. At least on the first occasion.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Now you're showing your age. Blair, Cameron, et al, are not nearly as well-read as the politicians of the Wilson/Jenkins/Crossman era. Nowadays political vocabulary is a big box of ready-made phrases that can be snapped together in different formations like Lego bricks. But it would never include a word like "pragmatic".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: So this question is indeed a duplicate after all, but not so much for questions where the best answer is *malapropism*. The unfortunate thing is that this kind of question is difficult to find via search unless you already know the answer. The duplicate linked above is definitely not the best match for this question. Better matches would be [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-word-to-describe-someone-who-often-inaccurately-uses-words) or [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138812/word-for-when-one-uses-the-wrong-word-in-a-sentence).

Comment: @John Y Yes; I almost put in the hedge 'You need to have taken part in 3 years' worth of discussions before you can take part in a discussion properly'. I haven't got the answer to this problem. One probably has to do a reasonable search and then post as if there is no previous treatment, accepting that people who've been around >x years but still have >y neurons will detect and flag dupes. It's nothing to lose sleep over ;-)

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting to spot a better example, and then I'll edit the question. It's definitely not a duplicate of the other question, or I'd have already marked an answer as correct. That might be the closest expression we have in the language for all I know, but it's not an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

[**Malapropism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) (or Dogberryism) is misuse of a word that sounds similar to another word that would have made sense.

See also: [**Bushisms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushism).

Comment: I don't think malapropism is exactly it, because often when I see or hear this there's not any relationship between the word used and any similar word that would have worked. For example, in the example I posted the person had picked up the mistaken idea somewhere along the line that supine means "to beg."

Comment: To come to someone with your hand out certainly means to come asking for something.  That figurative hand would certainly be in the supine position.  I really don't understand what you are asking.  A supine hand is certainly a hand in the begging position.

Comment: I think it's clear that OP has chosen a poor example to illustrate her question. That said, if you can get past that and look at the substance of her question, it's just as clear that *malapropism* isn't what she's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

'Heterophemy' but if conative, 'framis'

Comment: the term 'malapropism' is really a comedic device, and is based on the character 'Mrs. Malaprop' "noted for her ridiculous misuse of large words (e.g. contagious countries for contiguous countries"   http://etymology.enacademic.com/22804/malapropism