# Word for a misused word

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes the mistaking of a word for one that sounds similar. For instance "you aren't allowed to do that, but I guess we can make a deception." Obviously, "deception" should be "exception." The words don't sound the same, but they're pretty close.

Comment: Also see this question/answers: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/83232/18655

Comment: Also see this question/answers: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138812/word-for-when-one-uses-the-wrong-word-in-a-sentence

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps **[malapropism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/malaprop)**?

> The mistaken use of a word in place of a similar-sounding one, often with unintentionally amusing effect, as in, for example, “dance a flamingo” (instead of flamenco).

Comment: Perfect. I knew there was a word for this, but forgot it. Thanks bib!

Comment: Or the classic: "I'd rather be pissed off *then* pissed on"

Comment: @Cruncher Perhaps the order is reversed?

Answer (score 5):

Also [eggcorn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/eggcorn?q=eggcorn/)

> a word or phrase that results from a mishearing or misinterpretation of another, an element of the original being substituted for one that sounds very similar or identical (e.g. tow the line instead of toe the line ).

Comment: Best because eggcorn is itself an example.

Answer (score 3):

How about "[catachresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catachresis)?"

> catachresis: the incorrect use of words, as *luxuriant* for *luxurious*.

Answer (score 1):

A special class of this situation is a [mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen):

> the mishearing or misinterpretation of a phrase as a result of near-homophony, in a way that gives it a new meaning.